# Change DB name for Entity Framework DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have inherited an application which is using Entity Framework to access a SQL Server database. The `DbContext` class has the constructor as shown below, where `BuildingPermits` is the name of the initial catalog.

I would like to be able to switch between databases (with the same connection) via a config file instead of changing the code.

How can I accomplish this?

```
public BuildingPermitsDbContext() : base("BuildingPermits")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<BuildingPermitsDbContext>(null);
}
```

Comment: "BuildingPermits" is just the *name* of the connection string in the config file, not the connection string itself.

Comment: Not quite.  it would be the connection string if it was declared as ... base("name=BuildingPermits").  Here's how the connection string is (partially) defined in the .config file:

  <entityFramework>
 <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
   <parameters>
  <parameter value="Data Source=BCATSQL03,51000; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Initial Catalog=BuildingPermitsRN" />
   </parameters>
 ...
    />.

Comment: If you specify a database name parameter, then Code First creates a database with the name you specified in the base constructor in the local SQLEXPRESS database server. In order to switch name from config file you can either define complete connection string using "name=myDb1conn" or read dbName from custom setting from config file and use it in base(readDbName());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
using System.Configuration;

public BuildingPermitsDbContext() : base(DatabaseName())
{
    Database.SetInitializer<BuildingPermitsDbContext>(null);
}

private static string DatabaseName()
{ 
   var db = ConfigurationManager.AppSettingss["desiredDbName"];
   return db;
}
```